# Angular 2 service constructor with parameter

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I want to initialize a service with argument. Each component will have its own service instance.

```
@Injectable()
export class LoggingService {
  constructor( @Inject('group') @Optional() public group?: string) {
    this.group = group;
  }
}
```

It can be injected in to the component like this :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    templateUrl: 'test.component.html',
    providers: [
        LoggingService,
        { provide: 'group', useValue: 'Anythings goes here' }
    ]
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private logger : LoggingService) {

    }
}
```

**Above functionality is working fine for me.**

I also want to inject LoggingService into TimeCalculationService. How I can provide 'group' from TimeCalculationService

```
@Injectable()
export class TimeCalculationService {

    constructor(private logger : LoggingService) {

    }
}
```

Is there anything like this

```
@Injectable({
    providers : [
        { provide: 'group', useValue: 'Anythings goes here' }
    ]
})
```

Comment: You can create instance of service using `new` keyword. You can pass in the parameters during the Service object creation.

Comment: You can add `{ provide: 'group', useValue: 'Anythings goes here' }` in root modules `providers` option

Comment: Services are singleton in Angular. You can't create several instances of it. If you do, don't decorate them as injectable.

Comment: @trichetriche Not always, It Depends upon where the service is registered i.e `module` or `component`.

Comment: From what I have understood, services are decorated by `@Injectable` and declared as providers in the module. If they don't respect that, then they aren't services. Is that right ?